# Floating lstlisting - Getting it to split if longer than a page

Tags: floats, listings, page-breaking

When I put a long code in my file using a floating `lstlisting`, it is forced to be in only one page at the end of the chapter, and then some of the code is truncated and outside of the page. If I remove the float option, the code is "split" even though it would fit on a single page. It looks ugly.

What I want:

- place the listing at the top or bottom of some page close to the place in the TeX-code
- if the listing is to long for one page, continue on the next page, but don't split the code if it ***could*** fit on one page

Here's a minimal example to play around with. Notice that if the float-option is removed, it is placed 'correctly', but split. Also, the code will not continue on another page if you add as many linies to it that it would need a page break, but instead gets truncated. Furthermore, if one line is deleted from the listing it will behave as expected. Also, changing `lipsum[1]` to `lipsum[1-3]` shows what I would expect.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, float=htb]
Long listing start.
























Long listing end.
\end{lstlisting}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `float`s are not broken across the pages. If you want to break, don't use float. For caption you may use `captionof` macro from either `caption` ot `capt-of` packages.

Comment: @HarishKumar (+) Yes... but then the question will be: how can it be forced to fit on a page in the case that it will fit (even if that means putting it on the next page and continuing the text on this one)? At least, I take it that's the motivation to use floats although you are obviously right about their limitations.

Comment: @cfr: Probably `\afterpage`?

Comment: @HarishKumar That was what I wondered although I think that will put it on the next page even if there's room on this one, won't it? I guess the only way to prevent that, though, would be to use one of those needs-space things to figure out if there is room?

Comment: I changed the title; the behavior you get is not stupid at all: floats are *never* split, by design. What you want is a different feature; but the specifications you give are too loose.

Comment: @HarishKumar @egreg You are right about `float`s not being broken, I did not know/realize that. But still, I want the float to be placed near where I put it, not at the end of the chapter. I updated the description a bit to show the bahaviour I want (the last two sentences right before the MWE).

Comment: @HarishKumar I tried wrapping the `lstlisting` with `\afterpage{}`, but it just gives me an error:  `! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.
<to be read again> \par l.41 \lipsum[2-5]`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `float` option. A caption is also possible without it:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, caption=foo]
Long listing start.
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: If I don't use the `float` option the `lstlisting` will be split over pages, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Add the exclamation mark `!` in the float option to give the float placement a higher priority, so

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single, float=!htb]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Some restrictions on the float placement are ignored when including `!`.